# How to use Firebase API on Android without the Google Play Service dependency?

Tags: android, rest, firebase, google-play-services

I want to develop a Chat App on Android that uses the Firebase API. But the issue I found with the Firebase is that the App will not work properly if the device is no having the Google Play services installed in it.

When I tested the App on my personal device, it wasn't working in it even though the device had the Play Services in it, but an older version. I would really like to remove this dependency of Firebase on the Play services. Is there anyway?

Can we use the options like REST API or the Javascript calls from the mobile devices to connect to firebase?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for Android **is based** on Google Play Services.
You **can't** avoid or skip the dependencies.

If you want to use the REST API you can check the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), but only a few services are available.

Comment: Which Firebase services are not available with the REST API ?

Comment: @FebinMathew are available database and auth.

Comment: Could I move my documents from Firebase to Google Play Services to avoid user log in with Google/Facebook on my apps?

Comment: Now you can avoid this for some of the services: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of how to use Firebase Authentication on a device without Google Play services:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/auth-without-play-services

That will enable you to use Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage on devices without Google Play services as well.

Answer (score 5):

For some of the services, the new versions allow you to use it without Google Play Services

Details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't separate the two as Firebase is part of Google Play Services as mentioned in this [post](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/mobile-sdks-firebase-or-play-services/):

> Firebase is part of Google Play Services. It is not really a separate
>   SDK. However! Using Google Play Services as a whole is discouraged, to
>   say the least. Developers are encouraged to only pick and choose the
>   play services packages they need. In doing so, they “lose” Firebase
>   capabilities. In order to get them back, you need to specify which
>   Firebase packages you require, just like the other play services
>   packages.

Answer (score 4):

Since [firebase-auth 20.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v20-0-0) on October 27, 2020, Google Play services **is not required** for login.

See the full list of the [dependencies required for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services)